# Redirect or rewrite from one static URL to another static URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect one static URL to another static URL, but couldn't do it.

URL I want to redirect from:

```
http://www.eyecatchers.co/blogdetail.php?id=24%2FWHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-%E2%80%93-AN-EYECATCHERS%E2%80%99-TAKE%E2%80%A6..%2F
```

To this:

```
http://www.eyecatchers.co/blog/WHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-AN-EYECATCHERS-TAKE
```

I have tried with `301` redirect but couldn't help it out. Also tried with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blogdetail.php?id=24%2FWHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-%E2%80%93-AN-EYECATCHERS%E2%80%99-TAKE%E2%80%A6..%2F http://www.eyecatchers.co/blog/WHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-AN-EYECATCHERS-TAKE [R=301,L]
```

This does not work also.

Answer (score 0):

URL part after `?` represents a query string. You can not match  against `Query string` in RewriteRule's pattern. You need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}` or the full request header using  `{THE_REQUEST}` variable.

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blogdetail.php\?id=.+WHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.eyecatchers.co/blog/WHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-AN-EYECATCHERS-TAKE? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working ,It has given me 500 internal server error

Comment: To avoid the confusion I replaced all special uri chars with `.+` .Please try the updated rule.

Comment: Sorry this is also not working,gives me same 500 server error

Comment: Sorry there was a slight typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blogdetail.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=301,NC,L,R]
```

This would take care of all such links, i.e. */blogdetail.php?id=* will be simply replaced by */blog/*

Comment: Your rule will redirect `http: //www.eyecatchers.co/blogdetail.php?id=24%2FWHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-%E2%80%93-AN-EYECATCHERS%E2%80%99-TAKE%E2%80%A6..%2F` to `http: //www.eyecatchers.co/blog/24%2FWHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-%E2%80%93-AN-EYECATCHERS%E2%80%99-TAKE%E2%80%A6..%2F`

Comment: Oh, I thought that there were some characters in the FROM link, and they are there by mistake, my bad!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But now the question is /blogdetail.php?id= will be simply replaced by /blog/ , how 24%2F will remove from this link as it should be
http://www.eyecatchers.co/blog/WHY-YOUR-WEBSITE-IS-THE-NERVE-CENTER-OF-YOUR-ONLINE-MARKETING-AN-EYECATCHERS-TAKE

Comment: yeah, for that please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48314516/945214 by @starkeen. My solution would work for all normal URLs and is generic.